# mb_detect_encoding not working when using a $variable

Tags: php

I have a problem about method `mb_detect_encoding` in php, I have two cases  as bellow.

1. I input a string directly on method it is work perfect

`mb_detect_encoding("", "ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15")` result is `ASCII`, in this case is correct.

2. When I use a parameter put in method instead.

I have an array $strArray = ["戶", "凜", "", "", "", "井"];

I use bellow method to detect value encoding.

`mb_detect_encoding($strArray[2], "ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15")` result always is `UTF-8` instead `ASCII` like case 1.

What did I wrong here, Please help me in this case. I have spend a lot of time for it. Thank you so much.

Btw, This project is for Japanese so I use example is Japanese.

Comment: whats the encoding of the column which you save that value?

Comment: `` is ASCII?! I don't think so. Likely it's because when you hardcode the value in source code, its encoding is whatever your source code's encoding is, which may and up being ASCII depending on how your editor is treating it.

Comment: How can `mb_detect_encoding("", "ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15")` possibly return `ASCII`?

Comment: @Beginner My array is UTF-8 format. because I have a string `\u6236\u51DC\uE063\uE123井`, this string include `ASCII` and `UTF-8`, I have convert this string to array, and process for `ASCII` character in array.

Comment: @Loek Is is possible because this is that character `\uE063` when I debug it will be `""`

Comment: Well, yeah, none of these are ASCII. Please provide a complete, self contained example we could run ourselves to reproduce the same behaviour.